# Selective Continuous Integration with Git

Tags: css, git, deployment, continuous-integration

My Django project's team is looking to have the designer's CSS in a central place, preferably on the production server (so that there's one "truth" to the current design, a model he claims that he's worked with in the past).  Assuming that this is even a good practice, it would mean setting up Git to deploy the CSS in a Continuous Integration (CI) manner to production.

However, I would want to restrict Git somehow for the designer so that he doesn't accidentally update any files other than CSS or HTML.  Python and Django files would be updated by developers, who would be deploying in a more traditional manner: working in their own branches and only having a human build manager 
merging everything in to master when tested and ready.

Part of the reason that we want the designer to be able to deploy the CSS to a server is to avoid setting up the Django site locally on his laptop (he's not so technical outside of CSS, HTML, and Git).

1. Is this setup even a good idea?  If not, what's the proper alternative?
2. Assuming that we set up a CI config off of the master branch, and allow the CSS to be pushed to master, can I even restrict the designer's ability to modify and check in non-CSS/HTML files?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this setup even a good idea? If not, what's the proper alternative?

I have some reservations. It sounds like your designer is going to be the only person pushing changes to production without any gates: no code review, no tests, etc. Continuous integration is great, but a sane process includes safeties that prevent bad deploys. Since the rest of the team is following a different process, you'll end up managing two different pipelines. That's a waste of effort, and inevitably one of them (probably the designer's) falls apart due to lack of attention.

The alternative is put everyone on the same process. Teach the designer how to run the application locally, or build a harness that makes it easier. Unless your site is entirely static, how can they even see what their changes look like without that? Maybe it's more work to train them up, but it's an excellent opportunity for personal growth.

> Assuming that we set up a CI config off of the master branch, and allow the CSS to be pushed to master, can I even restrict the designer's ability to modify and check in non-CSS/HTML files? If so, how?

If you go this route, you can use [Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to restrict what the designer is allowed to commit. You can either put a `pre-commit` hook on their client or, if you control the server, a `pre-receive` hook that runs for only the designer's user. Either one can look at the committed files and block the commit/push if any are not CSS or HTML. There's a `pre-commit` framework called [Overcommit](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit) that might be helpful to you. If you're using a code review tool, most have places you can hook in a bot to leave a comment or block the merge when they've modified a file they shouldn't have.

Another option here is trust your coworker. Presumably they were hired because they're effective and useful, so you can save a lot of effort building up restrictions if instead everyone's clear on what they're supposed to be doing and generally doesn't screw it up.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks.